# eye gaze tracking from live webcam feed using opencv[computer vision]

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to find out the centre of the pupil of the eye from live webcam feed.I have used the DLib library to extract the eye region.After that I have used the minmaxLoc function of opencv on the eye region to detect the centre of the pupil.However,that coordinates of the pixel with minimum value(as the centre of the pupil is supposed to have the minimum value) is very unstable and continuously moving in the black region  of the eyeball.I have tried with averaging the coordinates across multiple frames but without much success.My aim is to ultimately build a gaze controlled mouse.There is no scope for usage of IR light as well.Any suggestions how to make that location stable??

Comment: try setting a window, i.e the periodic interval to read the data from webcam.i.e FPS. The FPS usually will be 60 or 30fps. try reducing it, and check if its not getting iffy.

Comment: @venkata krishnan,many many thanks sir for your advice.I